# ¿Para este mes de diciembre habrá sombreros secretos tal como el "Winter Bash" de Stack Overflow?

Tags: característica-nueva, discusión

Me pregunto si en StackOverflow en español, se podrán obtener sobreros secretos para este mes de diciembre!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Excelente pregunta!

Comment: Un poco ignorante yo pero, ¿de qué trata esto?

Comment: Hola Daniel, https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/12/winter-bash-2014/ es una temporada en la cual al participar en Stack Overflow te asigna somberos que puedes obtener bajo ciertas reglas, similares a la obtención de medallas, incluso hay sombreros secretos. Estos sombreros los usar en tu foto de perfil, es solo por diversión!. =)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Si, los habrá.  Necesito traducir unas cadenas primero y podremos lanzar esto.

Comment: @Elenasys me encantaría que me ayudaras pero si me ayudas, no serán sorpresa los sombreros....te mantendré en mente para proyectos en un futuro si todavía lo deseas

Comment: Véase [Presentamos Winter Bash 2015](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/questions/256/presentamos-winter-bash-2015).